# How should I order custom blocks?

Tags: theming

I have two blocks in a custom module.

```
function THEME_block_info(){
    $blocks = array();

    $blocks['contact_info'] = array(
        'info' => t('Contact Info Block'),//admin ui block name
    );
    $blocks['contact_form'] = array(
        'info' => t('Contact Form Block'),//admin ui block name
    return $blocks;
}

function THEME_block_view($delta = ''){
    $block = array();

    switch($delta){
        case 'contact_form':{
            $block['subject'] = t('');
            $block['content'] = build_contact($delta);
            break;
        }
        case 'contact_info':{
            $block['subject'] = t('');
            $block['content'] = build_contact($delta);
            break;
        }

}
```

These blocks show up in the admin UI where we are able to order them. However, the order set in the admin UI doesn't work.

How should I set the order of these custom blocks to make it match the one sets in through the UI?

Comment: clearing cache solved the problem

Comment: As side note, an empty string (`''`) doesn't need to be translated, since an empty string is still an empty string in every language. Instead of `t('')` just use `''`. Also, if that is the code of a module, the prefix for its functions should not be THEME.

Comment: It might be a typo but the array for contact_form in the hook_block_info() is not closed so you would get an error with that. Also, if the function build_contact() is part of your custom module, you should prefix the function with the name of the module to avoid potential problems in future.

Comment: And also this line is wrong: `case 'contact_form':{`. You don't use a curly parenthesis there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'weight' for every block.

```
$blocks['contact_info'] = array(
  'info' => t('Contact Info Block'),//admin ui block name
  'weight' => 0,
);

$blocks['contact_form'] = array(
  'info' => t('Contact Form Block'),
  'weight' => 1,
);
```

I hope this will work for you :)